# The advantages of using reflection over entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reflection

So I am starting up an MVC application with entity framework and have invited a friend who is more database heavy into the project and he suggested ditching entity framework and using reflection as an ORM (object relational mapper). Does anyone have any good web posts or literature to provide that would compare the two techniques and list out pro's / con's to both?

Comment: EF uses reflection, so the question doesn't really make sense. If you are using entity framework you will be using reflection.

Comment: `var mydata = db.Table.ToList();` - show me the reflection-based code for that. Then ask yourself that question again.

Comment: And let's not forget `System.Linq.Expressions`, so what about `var mydata = db.Table.Where(x => x.SomeDate > filterDate).ToList()`.

Comment: Your comparing apples to oranges here bud.

Comment: I don't understand how reflection by itself solves the problem of persisting objects to a database.

Comment: Reflection is not an ORM. Either your friend is confused or you misunderstood him.

Comment: I think I'm also confused what is "meant" by reflection here, but if you use DB first, and the latest EF, it will create objects for you automatically, which seems to be the desire??

Comment: Why don't your ask your friend this question.  That he's making the suggestion would imply he knows enough about both to suggest one over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ORM is a big complex product with lots of services, such as:

- materialization
- lazy loading
- persistence (including sequencing)
- change tracking
- identity management
- query abstraction (DSLs, LINQ/expression trees, etc)
- model abstraction (non-trivial mappings between the domain model and the data model)
- database vendor abstraction

Reflection can provide *a small part of that* - in particular it can help with materialization and inspection (for persistence etc), but not all the ORM features. Now, in a lot of cases you **don't need** all those features - which is fine. But reflection is (comparatively speaking): slow. Which is why tools like ORMs use a large amount of meta-programming to make them fast; and trust me - you *really* don't want to write lots of meta-programming code unless you are experienced in that area.

But: this is a solved problem - even if you don't want to use a full ORM, the areas touched upon by "reflection" are addressed by the smaller, simpler "micro-ORM"s - things like "dapper", "peta-poco", "simple.data". Before you go reinventing the wheel: try one of the micro-ORMs. They are a lot smaller and simpler, and usually quite noticeably *faster* than the full ORMs - and as the trade-off they don't offer the full wealth of services that full ORMs offer.

Comment: +1. I find Micro-ORMs the perfect trade-off - you get to hand-write the queries for performance, and end up with POCOs you can work with.

Comment: Marc - what is your opinion of Rob Conery's Massive micro-ORM?

Comment: @KarlAnderson it gets the job done; I prefer "dapper", though - I might be more than a little biased...

Comment: @MarcGravell - sure, sure, I understand your bias, thanks for the feedback.